# SSIS Execute SQL Task multi step with parameter mapping

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, execute-sql-task

I have a DTSX file that has an update statement that is selecting from itself in the update statement and it is filling up the temp DB.  It is using parameter mapping for a variable in the update statement.

I rewrote it to first run the select statement into a temp table and then run the update statement, but I get the following error "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors..."

I am not very familiar with SSIS packages and am wondering if I have written the statement incorrectly.

Below is the query.  Notice the update statement at the bottom has the "?" in it, which I thought would get the parameter mapped to it.

```
if OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#QUERYCF') is not null
  drop table #QUERYCF
go

select
        cafi_key,
        newfrequency.fr_key as cafi_freqkey,
        newcarriercharge.cacr_key as cafi_carrierchargekey,
        newcarrierrate.cara_key as cafi_carrierratekey
INTO #QUERYCF
    from stg_fct_carrierfinancial
    left outer join fin_dim_date chargedate
        on cafi_chargedtkey = chargedate.dt_key

    inner join fin_dim_carriercharge currentcarriercharge
        on cafi_carrierchargekey = currentcarriercharge.cacr_key
    inner join lkp_dim_carriercharge newcarriercharge
        on currentcarriercharge.cacr_db_code = newcarriercharge.cacr_db_code
        and currentcarriercharge.cacr_code = newcarriercharge.cacr_code
        and chargedate.dt_epochday between newcarriercharge.cacr_stdt_epochday and newcarriercharge.cacr_endt_epochday

    inner join fin_dim_frequency currentfrequency
        on cafi_freqkey = currentfrequency.fr_key
    inner join lkp_dim_frequency newfrequency
        on currentfrequency.fr_db_code = newfrequency.fr_db_code
        and currentfrequency.fr_pu_code = newfrequency.fr_pu_code
        and currentfrequency.fr_code = newfrequency.fr_code
        and chargedate.dt_epochday between newfrequency.fr_stdt_epochday and newfrequency.fr_endt_epochday

    inner join fin_dim_carrierrate currentcarrierrate
        on cafi_carrierratekey = currentcarrierrate.cara_key
    inner join lkp_dim_carrierrate newcarrierrate
        on currentcarrierrate.cara_db_code = newcarrierrate.cara_db_code
        and currentcarrierrate.cara_code = newcarrierrate.cara_code
        and chargedate.dt_epochday between newcarrierrate.cara_stdt_epochday and newcarrierrate.cara_endt_epochday

    where cafi_deleteloadkey is null and
    (
        currentcarriercharge.cacr_mostrecentcode = 0 or
        currentfrequency.fr_mostrecentcode = 0
    )

GO



update stg_fct_carrierfinancial
    set cafi_freqkey = newdata.cafi_freqkey,
    cafi_carrierchargekey = newdata.cafi_carrierchargekey,
    cafi_carrierratekey = newdata.cafi_carrierratekey,
    cafi_modifyloadkey = ?
from stg_fct_carrierfinancial currentdata
inner join (select
        cafi_key,
        cafi_freqkey,
        cafi_carrierchargekey,
        cafi_carrierratekey
FROM #QUERYCF
) newdata
on currentdata.cafi_key = newdata.cafi_key

GO

drop table #QUERYCF
GO
```

Here is the full error message:

> Build Facts (8/30/2019 10:40:25 PM)
>
> Message: ExecutionID:  Failure Code #-4001Source: Update obseleted dim
>   keys in stg_fct_carrierfinancial SubComponent: Execute SQL Task
>   ErrorCode: -1073548784 Description: Executing the query "
>
> select cafi_key, newfrequency.fr_key as cafi_..." failed with the
>   following error: "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors.
>   Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.".
>   Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet"
>   property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or
>   connection not established correctly.
>
> Source: Update obseleted keys in stg_fct_startstoprestarttrans
>   SubComponent: Execute SQL Task ErrorCode: -1073548784 Description:
>   Executing the query "
>
> select stsprstr_key, newfrequency.fr_key as s..." failed with the
>   following error: "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors.
>   Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.".
>   Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet"
>   property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or
>   connection not established correctly.
>
> Elapsed Time: 7800 secs Elapsed Time: 02:09:59 Return Code: -4001
>   (SSIS_EXECUTE_FAILURE)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the main problem is caused by aliases, since you have given `currentdata` as alias to `stg_fct_carrierfinancial` in the FROM clause, but you didn't use it in the UPDATE clause.

Try using the following query:

```sql
update currentdata
    set currentdata.cafi_freqkey = newdata.cafi_freqkey,
    currentdata.cafi_carrierchargekey = newdata.cafi_carrierchargekey,
    currentdata.cafi_carrierratekey = newdata.cafi_carrierratekey,
    currentdata.cafi_modifyloadkey = ?
from stg_fct_carrierfinancial currentdata 
inner join (select
        cafi_key,
        cafi_freqkey,
        cafi_carrierchargekey,
        cafi_carrierratekey
FROM #QUERYCF
) newdata
on currentdata.cafi_key = newdata.cafi_key

GO
```

Comment: Thanks.  I made the change and still got the error, but the error looks to be focused on the SELECT ... INTO #QUERYCF temp table.  Do you see any issue with running the SELECT in a "Execute SQL Task" in SSIS?

Comment: @markmccoid don't use any columns without mentioning the table alias name or the table name (if no alias is given). also when giving an alias to a table don't ever use its name again (always use the alias)